# Logs from Serverless framework is not showing on AWS CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless, serverless-framework

I am using serverless framework, AWS CodeCommit, CodeBuild, and CodePipeline. When I push my code and CodeBuild starts to deploy it, I don't get any feedback or logs from serverless framework inside the CloudWatch log groups.

I am using the default service roles for CodeBuild and CodePipeline which are created by AWS when I first created a new PipeLine and CodeBuild. Both of those roles include polices for CloudWatch and create log groups as follows:

**CodeBuild**

```
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:*****:log-group:/aws/codebuild/sis-notes-backend-codebuild",
            "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:*****:log-group:/aws/codebuild/sis-notes-backend-codebuild:*"
        ],
        "Action": [
            "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:PutLogEvents"
        ]
   },
```

**CodePipeline**

```
"Action": [
            "elasticbeanstalk:*",
            "ec2:*",
            "elasticloadbalancing:*",
            "autoscaling:*",
            "cloudwatch:*",
            "s3:*",
            "sns:*",
            "cloudformation:*",
            "rds:*",
            "sqs:*",
            "ecs:*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Effect": "Allow"
    },
```

And this is the output of CloudWatch log groups. As you can see that I've wrote rubbish in the deploy code in order to get an error or failed response back from Serverless, but I got nothing just empty lines.

[image: CloudWatch]

**buildspec.yml**

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo Installing Serverless
      - npm install -g serverless
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Install source NPM dependencies
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Deployment started on `date`
      - echo Deploying with the Serverless Framework
      - sls deploy -v -s $ENV_NAMEss kklksadk
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Deployment completed on `date`
```

**serverless.yml**

```
service: sls-notes-backend
frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  region: us-west-2
  stage: prod
  memorySize: 128
  timeout: 4
  endpointType: regional
  environment:
    NOTES_TABLE: ${self:service}-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}

resources:
  Resources:
    NotesTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.NOTES_TABLE}
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: user_id
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: timestamp
            AttributeType: N
          - AttributeName: note_id
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: user_id
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: timestamp
            KeyType: RANGE
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          - IndexName: note_id_index
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: note_id
                KeyType: HASH
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: ALL
            ProvisionedThroughput:
              ReadCapacityUnits: 2
              WriteCapacityUnits: 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sls deploy -v` will only output the version information and exit. It's a greedy match.

Change the `-v` flag to `--verbose` and this will work.

Example:

```
➜  js-library-test sls deploy -v
Running "serverless" from node_modules
Framework Core: 3.1.1 (local) 3.12.0v (global)
Plugin: 6.0.0
SDK: 4.3.1

➜  js-library-test
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried your solution but It didn't work. In fact, I am getting an error. https://ibb.co/QdQqRVS

Comment: I don't think this is the right solution. You can see that in this tutorial the -v flag is used, and he is getting a feedback from serverless, whereas I got just empty lines. 
https://ibb.co/6Jzzhyn

Comment: No, it's working now. You're just getting a new error because it's finally attempting to deploy. Now it appears you're getting a stack creation error. The `-v` flag in the image you show here is from serverless version 1.0, so the tutorial you're following is out of date.

Comment: The new error you're seeing is a Forbidden error. Likely your codebuild instance doesn't have the right credentials needed to deploy the CloudFormation stack. If you expand it fully, you should see a full stack trace and error description. Either way your original question is answered, so please accept my answer and open a new question if necessary. Thanks!